# Angular UI date picker validation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/XQY1TJ7XdqLcx0MxwHAd?p=preview) I have an Angular UI date picker and a message that should be shown only when the date is valid. The problem is that the message is always shown, even when `form.$valid` is true. Note that if you enter a valid or invalid date and then click on `Validate`, an alert will display correctly that the date is valid or invalid respectively.

Why is the validation message shown all the time, even when `form.$valid` is true?

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('ctl', function ($scope) {


    $scope.dtFrom = new Date ();

    $scope.config1 = {};
    $scope.config1.opened = false;
    $scope.open1 = function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         event.stopPropagation();
         $scope.config1.opened = true;
    };

    $scope.validate = function(form){
        if (!form.$valid) {
           alert("Date invalid");
        }
        else {
           alert("Date valid");
        }
    }

});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="ctl">
  <form name="form1" ng-submit="validate(form1)" novalidate>
      <p class="input-group" name="dtFrom" style="width:160px;margin-bottom:0px;">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="dtFrom" 
               is-open="config1.opened"  uib-datepicker-popup="MM-dd-yyyy" 
               close-text="Close" />
           <span class="input-group-btn">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1($event)">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
               </button>
           </span>
      </p>
      <span ng-show="!form1.dtFrom.$valid">Invalid Date</span>
      <br/>
      <button type="submit">Validate</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create name for  the input

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="dtFrom" 
                   is-open="config1.opened"  uib-datepicker-popup="MM-dd-yyyy" 
                   close-text="Close" name="date" />
      <span ng-show="!form1.date.$valid">Invalid Date</span>
```

Here is plnkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/gc0Oefhok6Gjim66UG0K?p=preview

Comment: the name of the field is `dtFrom`, why did you change it to `date` ? using `dtFrom` with your solution doesn't work, see here http://plnkr.co/edit/aGyLQccXIuQxO6QKb4Hv?p=preview

Comment: @ps0604 name of `input` not name of `p`tag . see here http://plnkr.co/edit/OHuJ2FxP0YCFjTivsIqH?p=preview